# How can I extract data from an XML file?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I've got an XML file called `goldbach.xml`. 
It contains slots (1 or 2 per hour) with several spots (a spot is a short video or an advertising)

From that file, I need to extract the following information:

```
<slot>
    <starttimeUTC>1519189200000</starttimeUTC>
    <durationAbsolute>7000</durationAbsolute>
    <materialName>01 07 LILLYDOO 2018 dm DE KINO WM</materialName>
</slot>
```

The `goldbach.xml` file looks like

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ProgramDataExchange>
    <header>
        <channel>KINO</channel>
        <channelID>KINO</channelID>
        <versionInternal>2018-02-14T10:42:14.543</versionInternal>
        <versionExternal>2018-02-14T10:42:14.543</versionExternal>
        <dateFrom>2018-02-21</dateFrom>
        <dateTo>2018-02-21</dateTo>
    </header>
    <broadcastDay>
        <txDay></txDay>
        <slot>
            <starttimeUTC>1519189200000</starttimeUTC>
            <duration>7800000</duration>
            <slotID>574813</slotID>
            <slotTypeID>1</slotTypeID>
            <program>       
                <programName>9 Rota</programName>       
            </program>
            <interruption>
                <interruptionID>565290</interruptionID>
                <position>-1</position>             
                <break>
                    <breakID>565290</breakID>                   
                    <spot>  
                        <durationAbsolute>7000</durationAbsolute>                       
                        <materialName>01 07 LILLYDOO 2018  WM</materialName>
                    </spot>
                    <!-- ... -->
                </break>
                <!-- ... -->
            </interruption>
            <!-- ... -->
        </slot>
        <!-- ... -->
    </broadcastDay>
    <!-- ... -->
</ProgramDataExchange>
```

Comment: the output on the php page should look like this ?

<slot><starttimeUTC>1519189200000</starttimeUTC>
<durationAbsolute>7000</durationAbsolute>< materialName>01 07 LILLYDOO 2018 dm DE KINO WM</materialName>

Comment: What is `goldenbach.xml`? Please include a [minimal, verifyable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make it easier to help you and edit your question. Right now, I feel like it's unclear what exactly you're asking.

Comment: goldenbach.xml is ny xml file name, i want to make output like this -->  <slot><starttimeUTC>1519189200000</starttimeUTC> <durationAbsolute>7000</durationAbsolute>< materialName>01 07 LILLYDOO 2018 dm DE KINO WM</materialName>

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help because I don't know what exactly your problem is.